# Command to stop querying in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a long SQL Script which I run to pre-populate some temp tables.  At the bottom of the script, I have some queries that I run manually, as well as some other ad-hoc queries.  I open the query, then get it started (takes a few minutes to run).  However, I don't want all the queries at the end of script to run - I only want to the temp tables to populate.

`SQL Server 2008 Management Studio` has a "breakpoint" function that will stop the script at that point, but if you close the application and re-open it, it will forget the breakpoint (only lasts for the session in which you set it).

I could comment out the queries at the bottom and run them manually.  However, the ideal solution for me was to include a command in my script to stop the script from running.

In `SQL Server 2008` is there a command I can put into my script that will stop processing at a specific location?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put a RETURN at the place where you want to stop executing the script.

Comment: RETURN is only valid within a stored procedure / function etc. You can't put this in an ad hoc batch. I wasn't the one who down-voted, btw.

Comment: I just tried it in SQL Server 2008 and it worked fine. (two select queries with a return between them, only executed the first one).

Comment: Interesting, this might show my age but at some point it was not valid syntax outside of a module. I'll +1 to offset whoever down-voted you.

Comment: @AaronBertrand : If you have a empty RETURN statement then will it not stop the execution? I also tried it and it seem to work for me as well.

Comment: RETURN would not work if script contains multiple GO statements though.

Comment: Yes, that is true, RETURN is only returning control for the current batch.

Comment: Ya, if you have a GO after the return it will continue after that go.

Comment: Talk about a resurrection... this turned around quick.

Comment: Great answer.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Another potential solution is to put a waitfor command so that the script pauses. If you can identify that the script has made it to that point, you can stop it at any time, as long as you don't wait longer than the waitfor. e.g.

```
-- first part of script

RAISERROR('Finished above section, about to wait...', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
WAITFOR DELAY '23:59:59';

-- rest of script
```

You could also do this conditionally, e.g.

```
DECLARE @stop BIT = 0;

-- first part of script

IF @stop = 1
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Finished above section, about to wait...', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
    WAITFOR DELAY '23:59:59';
END

-- rest of script
```

Comment: +1: Shoot! That's what I was going to post, but I thought I would have gotten pummeled for misusing the function. I guess it's not a bad approach, all things considered :-)

Comment: It is kind of kludgy, and I can't say I'm very proud that it's the first option that came to mind...

Comment: So you will actually crash the script for it to exit?

Comment: Hitting Stop during a `WAITFOR` isn't exactly "crashing" - it's just telling SQL Server to stop waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Add somethig like

If (false) then
   Run your queries

And change it to true just when you want to execute them

Comment: ...or just highlight the portion inside the IF. However, this has the same problem as RETURN... if the portion to execute has multiple GOs, your single IF can't span multiple batches.

Answer (score -3):

But the queries at the end wrapped in a comment block, e.g.

/*

your queries here

*/

Comment: Op already said in his/her question that commenting is an option